# Video Element Not Autoplaying

Tags: html, html5-video, autoplay

I have a video element with autoplay, muted, and loop. Occasionally Chrome will play the video but the vast majority of the time the video wont play at all.`

```
 <video autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="assets/images/poster.webp">
                        <source  src="assets/images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
```

I've tried all sorts of different variations but in the end of the day the result remains the same.

Comment: Welcome to [so] - Please read the [ask] page and include a [mre] of the issue you are having

Comment: @Judah autoplay is stopped by browser like chrome. Until user interact, it will not autoplay.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.